# session.execute returns model objects instead of actual data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have switched from `connection.execute` to `session.execute`. I am not able to get usable data from it. The results seem to contain references to models instead of actual row data.

```py
with Session(engine) as s:
    q = select(WarrantyRequest)
    res = s.execute(q)
    keys = res.keys()
    data_list = res.all()
    print(keys)      # should print list of column names
    print(data_list) # should print list of lists with row data
    dict_list = s.execute(q).mappings().all()
    print(dict_list) # should print list of dicts with column names as keys
```

It prints

```
RMKeyView(['WarrantyRequest'])
[(<models.mock.WarrantyRequest object at 0x7f4d065d3df0>,), ...]
[{'WarrantyRequest': <models.mock.WarrantyRequest object at 0x7f002b464df0>}, ... ]
```

When doing the same with `connection.execute`, I got the expected results.

What am I missing?

There is this paragraph in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#querying-2-0-style) which kind of describes the  behaviour, but I am not able to tell what I am supposed to do to get data out of it.

> It’s important to note that while methods of Query such as Query.all() and Query.one() will return instances of ORM mapped objects directly in the case that only a single complete entity were requested, the Result object returned by Session.execute() will always deliver rows (named tuples) by default; this is so that results against single or multiple ORM objects, columns, tables, etc. may all be handled identically.
> If only one ORM entity was queried, the rows returned will have exactly one column, consisting of the ORM-mapped object instance for each row. To convert these rows into object instances without the tuples, the Result.scalars() method is used to first apply a “scalars” filter to the result; then the Result can be iterated or deliver rows via standard methods such as Result.all(), Result.first(), etc.

Comment: Is`WarrantyRequest` a model or a table?

Comment: its a model class.

Comment: Querying a model return rows that consist of individual model instances.  If you want to use `session.execute` but get rows of raw data then query the model's `__table__` attribute: `q = select(WarrantyRequest.__table)))`

Comment: This worked, thank you. If you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept. As a side question, do you know what this list of model references is good for?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand - model instances let you treat rows as model instances, so instead of having a row like `('Alice', 42)` you have a `Person` class that defines the row structure and you can access column data as attributes `person.name`, `person.age`.  Does that answer your side question?

Comment: kind of, I guess it depends on what you are goind to do with the query result. In my case I just want send them as json response or similar to a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying a model

```py
q = select(WarrantyRequest)
```

returns rows that consist of individual model instances. To get rows of raw data instead, query the model's `__table__` attribute:

```py
q = select(WarrantyRequest.__table__)
```

SQLAlchemy's ORM layer presents database tables and rows in an object-oriented way, on the assumption that the programmer wants to work with objects and their attributes rather than raw data.